# NiFi accessing attributes Python3

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apache-nifi

I am trying to use external scripts that are Python3  using the ExecuteScript or ExecuteStreamCommand to run the code.

I currently use the sys library to read the content of the flowfiles and process them and the print command to create the flowfile content.

```
import sys


for responses in sys.stdin:
    print(responses)
```

I see NiFi natively supports Jython 2.7 and I see there's a good cookbook (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) that provides samples on how to achieve some tasks using Jython..

I would like to understand what libraries would be required to do the same steps using Python3 so that I would be able to read the flowfiles (content & attributes) within my scripts.

So that I can access the `session` within NiFi so that I can have access to the attributes and the content of the flowfile.

Comment: `Executescript` is using jython (java-based python) - there is nothing about python3, but you could read/write attributes and examples could be found in a cookbook.  `ExecuteStreamCommand` executes system command, so you could execute python3 installed near by nifi, but you can't access attributes there - only content.

Comment: Thanks @daggett for the response, I mistyped the processer as `Executescript` instead of `ExecuteProcess` so there is no libraries that could be used within Python3 that can actually do the same task as reading the session attributes and content file. 
As if its the case I would need to bring the Attributes as a value within the content of the flowfile to be able to process it. 
Would it be possible to access variables within the Python3 script, and if yes would it be possible to attach the attributes to variables as expression language ?

Comment: executeprocess can't access attributes also, however inside nifi you could put/add attributes into content - format depends on what do you want to do with current flow file content... https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AttributesToJSON/index.html converts attributes to json content but current content will be dropped.